# state-machines/state_machine - Next state in transitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I'm using https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines for Rails for storing and doing work before and after a state change of an object.

What I'd like to do is have a single method which can be called in a `before_transition` for a given set of `events`, and for a given `event`, have the method called by the `before_transition` do something a bit differently.

For example, say the method is called `log_state_change`, something like:

```rb
def log_state_change
  case <???>
  when "successful"
    Rails.logger.info "Successful"
  when "failure"
    Rails.logger.info "Failure"
  when "starting_run"
    Rails.logger.info "Starting run" 
  else
    Rails.logger.error "Unknown"
end
```

I can find no methods that would fit for `<???>` above. Perhaps someone more familiar with this gem could assist please?

Comment: Do you mean all of these to be values like `'successful'` or `:successful` instead of variables? I'd guess `case state` would do the job which returns a string. Never underestimate things like `Rails.logger.info(state.titleize)`

Comment: I do, but the state I'm transitioning _to_, not the state that I'm currently _in_. I'll update the question to reflect the string of state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accept an argument on your `before_transition` callback and obtain all data you need to implement an expected behaviour.

The code which passes the argument you can find at [the source code of the library](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines/blob/e60fe9600b53d94484c7a3431aad994fc6a1e9d3/lib/state_machines/callback.rb#L200-L218). You can implement this logic with `around_transition` as well.

```rb
require 'state_machines'

class Light

  state_machine :state, initial: :off do

    before_transition from: any, do: :log_me

    event :light do
      transition all => :on
    end

    event :dark do
      transition [:on] => :off
    end

  end

  def log_me(transition)
    case transition.event
    when :light
      p "`light` event was called to transition from #{transition.from} to #{transition.to}"
    when :dark
      p "`dark` event was called to transition from #{transition.from} to #{transition.to}"
    else
      p "`#{transition.event}` was called to transition from #{transition.from} to #{transition.to}"
    end
  end
end

a = Light.new

a.light # => "`light` event was called to transition from off to on"
a.dark # => "`dark` event was called to transition from on to off"
```